# IOS authentication to web service with facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, web-services, security

Currently I am developing a simple game that uses facebook to authorize users. After user is connected to the facebook, the client makes web service calls to the server in order to get stats of the user, start new game etc.

I am already using SSL for the connection between server and client. The problem I am trying to tackle is this:

The data is sent to the web service in clear text. Since I do not have any authentication mechanism other than facebook login (no username/password login etc.) anyone can sniff and forge a web service packet and perform operations on the server.

What is the logical approach to this ? How does other games such as bejeweled where you can connect with your facebook account only overcome this problem?

Comment: "The data is sent to the web service in clear text."  So don't sent it in the clear, use SSL.

Comment: What I mean is, the line is encypted using SSL as I mentioned "I am already using SSL for the connection between server and client."
The problem is the source, if one installs a proxy such as Charles, they can see the data in the source client and modify/resend it.

Comment: The client can always modify their own traffic.  No authentication scheme can change that.